# In Wagtail, how can I add a form to the bottom of another model's form in the WagtailAdmin, for a OneToOneField relationship?

Tags: django, wagtail

In Wagtail, let's say I have a page like this:

```
class MyPage(Page):
    field_1 = RichTextField()
    field_2 = models.DateField()

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('field_1'),
        FieldPanel('field_2'),
    ]
```

And I have another model which has a one-to-one relationship with the first model:

```
class PageSettings(models.Model):
    page = models.OneToOneField(MyPage)
    extra_setting_1 = models.BooleanField()
    extra_setting_2 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

How can I add a form for the PageSettings model to the bottom of the Wagtail admin form for the MyPage model?

Bonus points for a way to do it with generic relationships.

Comment: As you've already mentioned at https://github.com/torchbox/wagtail/issues/1831, it looks like this isn't supported currently. I think their intent for this kind of thing (at least for now) is to use inheritance and add those attributes as part of your `MyPage` class instead.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right.  The more I get to know the code base, the more it seems that it's not set up to allow this kind of approach.  I'll post an answer here if I ever figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyPage(Page):
    field_1 = RichTextField()
    field_2 = models.DateField()

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('field_1'),
        FieldPanel('field_2'),
        InlinePanel('settings', label='Settings', min_num=1, max_num=1),
    ]    

class PageSettings(models.Model):
    page = ParentKey(MyPage, related_name='settings')
    extra_setting_1 = models.BooleanField()
    extra_setting_2 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Comment: I like this answer - I haven't 'accepted' it because it doesn't exactly fulfill the requirements (I want to do it with a OneToOneField), and the form it results in has some unwanted buttons that don't make sense with one to one relationships, but it's a good workaround.

Comment: Wagtail doesn't like O2O, but you could hack together a ParentalOneToOneField. The GUI problem could be solved with an included editor javascript that made the styling changes required, or a custom InlinePanel with a custom template.